# JPA soft delete with @SqlDelete causes SQL error: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have `Basket` and `BasketItem` entities that both extend `BaseEntity` as below:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
    private Boolean deleted = false;

    @Version @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long version;
}

@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE basket SET deleted=true WHERE id=?")
public class Basket extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "basket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BasketItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE basketItem SET deleted=true WHERE id=?")
public class BasketItem extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "basket_id", nullable = false)
    private Basket basket;
}
```

Now when I want to delete a `BasketItem` from a `Basket`, I just call `remove(basketItem)` on basket items list and save the `Basket` instance:

```java
@Service
public class DeleteBasketItemUseCase {

    @Transactional
    public BasketOutput execute(final Long itemId, final Long basketId) {
        // loading and checks omitted 
        basket.getItems().remove(basketItem);
        basket = basketRepository.save(basket);
    }
}
```

Deleting `basketItem` generates `MySQL` error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)
```

Generated SQL in log is:

```
UPDATE
        basketItem 
    SET
        deleted=true 
    WHERE
        id = ?
```

I am using

- `Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE`
- `MySQL 8.0`
- `Hibernate 5.4.12.Final`
- `mysql-connector-java-8.0.19`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I update `@SQLDelete` and add `and version=?` AT the end of annotation:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE basket SET deleted=true WHERE id=? and version=?")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE basket_item SET deleted=true WHERE id=? and version=?")
```

Note: Also I've changed database tables names!